# How to make a button change an <h2> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working random song generator which has a button to play and pause, and a button to randomize the songs. I do this through the `rand` and `s` variables, its not the best way but it works. I want the reveal button to reveal what the song is when its pressed, but  i don't know how id go about that, can anyone help?

HTML:

```html
<audio id="1st" >
        <source src="intervals/1st.mp3" type = "audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

    <audio id="2nd" >
        <source src="intervals/2nd.mp3" type = "audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

    <audio id="3rd">
        <source src="intervals/3rd.mp3" type= "audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

     <audio id="4th">
        <source src="intervals/4th.mp3" type= "audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

    <audio id="5th">
        <source src="intervals/5th.mp3" type= "audio/mp3"/>
    </audio>

    <audio id="6th">
        <source src="intervals/6th.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

    <audio id="7th">
        <source src="intervals/7th.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

    <button type="button" id="reveal">Reveal</button>
    <button type="button" id="playButton"></button>
    <button type="button" id="randomise"></button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var playButtonJS = document.getElementById('playButton');
var randomiseJS = document.getElementById('randomise');
var revealJS = document.getElementById("reveal");
var FstJS = document.getElementById('1st');
var SndJS = document.getElementById('2nd');
var TrdJS = document.getElementById('3rd');
var FOthJS = document.getElementById('4th');
var FIthJS = document.getElementById('5th');
var SIthJS = document.getElementById('6th');
var SEthJS = document.getElementById('7th');


var audioPlaying = [FstJS, SndJS, TrdJS,FOthJS, FIthJS, SIthJS, SEthJS];

var rand = audioPlaying[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];

playButtonJS.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
randomiseJS.addEventListener('click', random, false);
revealJS.addEventListener('click', rev, false);

function random() {
    rand.pause();
    playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(playbutton.svg)';
    var song = audioPlaying[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];
    playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pausebutton.png)';
    songf(song);
}

function songf(s) {
    rand.currentTime=0;
    rand = s;

    if (!s.paused && !s.ended) {
        s.pause();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(playbutton.svg)';
    }
    else {
        s.play();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pausebutton.png)';
    }
}

function playOrPause() {
    if (!rand.paused && !rand.ended) {
        rand.pause();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(playbutton.svg)';
    }
    else {
        rand.play();
        playButtonJS.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pausebutton.png)';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean contents within the tag?

Comment: yes. if for example the song chosen was song1, i want the h2 tag to then say, "song 1"

Comment: You're using ID the wrong way. That's exactly the type of example when classes kick in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JQuery solution:**

Assign to your rand variable the numeric value of the index of the song that you are playing instead the value of the data selected from the array. Or make a intermediate variable as 'selectedindex'.
Why? Because a number is what will help you here to refer specific data.

Then decide how you want to give the info to the user.
Imagine you put some labels `<h2 id="name1">Name of the song</h2>...<h2 id ="name6">...` up of every song tag.
Initially style them with display:none;
.
And you can do something like

```
function reveal () {
   $("#name+rand").style.display = "block";
   console.log('You are playing the song number', rand)
}
```

If you prefer a common container/div/h2 to give the info, you can replace inner HTML with:

```
$("#label").html('Song is the number: '+ selectedIndex);
```

without using JQuery translation:

```
document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "Song is number" +      
String(selectedIndex);
```

Or use the number to give the name of the song from an array of names.

```
$("#label").html('Song is:'+ ArrayOfNames[selectedIndex]);
```

without using JQuery translation:

```
document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "Song is" +    
ArrayOfNames[selectedIndex];
```

Edit: I recommend you use JQuery if you are going to add this class of features.

Comment: I'm not very confident on JQuery, i would add it in if i had a bit more experience, so i'm using JavaScript. I'm trying to do what you said here: `selectedIndex = audioPlaying[rand];
    document.getElementByID('ans').innerHTML = String(selectedIndex);`                                                    
                                                                                                              As I believe `rand` is giving me a random number or am i not correct? When i run this it chnges the h2 tag to "undefined"

Comment: var rand = audioPlaying[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length)];

Here you say rand is the value of the Array. Then it is FstJS, SndJS, TrdJS...

var audioPlaying = [FstJS, SndJS, TrdJS,FOthJS, FIthJS, SIthJS, SEthJS];

var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * audioPlaying.length);

var randValue = audioPlaying[randIndex];

[optional] var randSongName = ArrayOfNames[randIndex]

Comment: What I suggested is you to store the random number you generate then you have the numeric value of what song is playing. Imagine, it is 3. Then use it to get data from arrays, using it as index. The name of the song 3, the html identifier of the song 3...

Comment: That's not "pure JS", it's "pure DOM." The *language* is JavaScript whether you're using jQuery or not.

Comment: Good clarification. I meant that he did not need to integrate JQuery. Yep. I edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following codeline to wherever you are handling the change in the music played. replace th "songTitle" with relevent html tag id and Song name with relevant one.

```
document.getElementById("songTitle").innerHTML = "New song name";
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I want that to happen, however what the text changes to depends on what song is actually playing

Answer (score 0):

```js
var songNames = ["songName_1", "songName_2", "songName_3", "songName_4"];



function randomSong() {
  var songName = arguments[0][randomNum(0, songNames.length - 1)];
  document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = songName;
}

document.getElementById("randomSong").addEventListener("click", function() {
  randomSong(songNames);
})


function randomNum(minNum, maxNum) {
  switch (arguments.length) {
    case 1:
      return parseInt(Math.random() * minNum + 1, 10);
      break;
    case 2:
      return parseInt(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1) + minNum, 10);
      break;
    default:
      return 0;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 id="songName"></h2>

<input id="randomSong" type="button" value="randomSong!" />
```

This is what I understand the meaning of brother, your code is really a bit messy, if there are problems you can ask me.

I have a better solution, but now I am at work and later sent to you.